# Is Allah fair with every humanbeing?

Tags: allah, divine-justice

Assalamualaikum Brothers/Sisters,

I need an ayath from the Quran which says that Allah is fair with every human being. Even the Non-Muslims.

Jazakallahi Khair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> مَنْ عَمِلَ صَالِحًا فَلِنَفْسِهِ وَمَنْ أَسَاءَ فَعَلَيْهَا وَمَا
>   رَبُّكَ بِظَلَّامٍ لِلْعَبِيدِ
>
> Whoever does righteousness - it is for his [own] soul; and whoever
>   does evil [does so] against it. And your Lord is not ever unjust to
>   [His] servants.
>
> [quran 41:46](https://quran.com/41/46)

---

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَظْلِمُ مِثْقَالَ ذَرَّةٍ وَإِنْ تَكُ حَسَنَةً
>   يُضَاعِفْهَا وَيُؤْتِ مِنْ لَدُنْهُ أَجْراً عَظِيماً
>
> Indeed, Allah does not do injustice, [even] as much as an atom's
>   weight; while if there is a good deed, He multiplies it and gives from
>   Himself a great reward.
>
> [quran 4:40](https://quran.com/4/40)

---

> هَلْ يَنظُرُونَ إِلَّا أَن تَأْتِيَهُمُ الْمَلَائِكَةُ أَوْ يَأْتِيَ
>   أَمْرُ رَبِّكَ ۚ كَذَٰلِكَ فَعَلَ الَّذِينَ مِن قَبْلِهِمْ ۚ وَمَا
>   ظَلَمَهُمُ اللَّهُ وَلَٰكِن كَانُوا أَنفُسَهُمْ يَظْلِمُونَ
>
> Do the disbelievers await [anything] except that the angels should
>   come to them or there comes the command of your Lord? Thus did those
>   do before them. And Allah wronged them not, but they had been wronging
>   themselves.
>
> [Quran 16:33](https://quran.com/16/33)

---

> الْيَوْمَ تُجْزَىٰ كُلُّ نَفْسٍ بِمَا كَسَبَتْ ۚ لَا ظُلْمَ الْيَوْمَ
>   ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ سَرِيعُ الْحِسَابِ
>
> This Day every soul will be recompensed for what it earned. No
>   injustice today! Indeed, Allah is swift in account.
>
> [quran 40:17](https://quran.com/40/17)

---

> وَنَضَعُ الْمَوَازِينَ الْقِسْطَ لِيَوْمِ الْقِيَامَةِ فَلَا تُظْلَمُ
>   نَفْسٌ شَيْئًا ۖ وَإِن كَانَ مِثْقَالَ حَبَّةٍ مِّنْ خَرْدَلٍ
>   أَتَيْنَا بِهَا ۗ وَكَفَىٰ بِنَا حَاسِبِينَ
>
> And We place the scales of justice for the Day of Resurrection, so no
>   soul will be treated unjustly at all. And if there is [even] the
>   weight of a mustard seed, We will bring it forth. And sufficient are
>   We as accountant.
>
> [quran 21:47](https://quran.com/21/47)

---

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَظْلِمُ مِثْقَالَ ذَرَّةٍ ۖ وَإِن تَكُ حَسَنَةً
>   يُضَاعِفْهَا وَيُؤْتِ مِن لَّدُنْهُ أَجْرًا عَظِيمًا
>
> Indeed, Allah does not do injustice, [even] as much as an atom's
>   weight; while if there is a good deed, He multiplies it and gives from
>   Himself a great reward.
>
> [quran 4:40](https://quran.com/4/40)

Comment: @DataShark welcome :)